# What is the effect of defining quota policy on existing OCI resources?

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Suppose I have a service limit of 10 compute instances in an availability zone and I am currently running 2 compute instances in a compartment "C01". Now, I have added a Quota statement to restrict the number of compute instances to ZERO in "C01". So, this will result in termination of existing instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, setting the quota won’t trigger any instance terminations. It will just block users from creating new instances.